# python regex for repeating string

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I am wanting to verify and then parse this string (in quotes):

```
string = "start: c12354, c3456, 34526; other stuff that I don't care about"
//Note that some codes begin with 'c'
```

I would like to verify that the string starts with 'start:' and ends with ';'
Afterward, I would like to have a regex parse out the strings. I tried the following python re code:

```
regx = r"start: (c?[0-9]+,?)+;" 
reg = re.compile(regx)
matched = reg.search(string)
print ' matched.groups()', matched.groups()
```

I have tried different variations but I can either get the first or the last code but not a list of all three.

Or should I abandon using a regex?

EDIT: updated to reflect part of the problem space I neglected and fixed string difference.
      Thanks for all the suggestions - in such a short time.

Comment: Indent code 4 spaces or use the "{}" button in the post editor.  I fixed it for you.  BTW, did you mean "V1 OIDs" or "start"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python, this isn’t possible with a single regular expression: each capture of a group overrides the last capture of that same group (in .NET, this would actually be possible since the engine distinguishes between captures and groups).

Your easiest solution is to *first* extract the part between `start:` and `;` and then using a regular expression to return *all* matches, not just a single match, using [`re.findall('c?[0-9]+', text)`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall).

Comment: Looks right to me. You can also check this out.   But you can use regex to find the start: and ; and do a two step process.  And you might want to check this out.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099178/matching-nested-structures-with-regular-expressions-in-python

Comment: Thanks, I wondered about regex groups and repetition for a single regex search() call. I had switched over to using findall() as well but I asked the question here just to see if there was a better way.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the standard string tools, which are pretty much always more readable.

`s = "start: c12354, c3456, 34526;"`

`s.startswith("start:") # returns a boolean if it starts with this string`

`s.endswith(";") # returns a boolean if it ends with this string`

`s[6:-1].split(', ') # will give you a list of tokens separated by the string ", "`

Comment: Yeah, I know that I *could* use straight string parsing but it I would have to code verifying the string format, versus with a regex you get that right off the bat.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done (pretty elegantly) with a tool like [Pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/Examples):

```
from pyparsing import Group, Literal, Optional, Word
import string

code = Group(Optional(Literal("c"), default='') + Word(string.digits) + Optional(Literal(","), default=''))
parser = Literal("start:") + OneOrMore(code) + Literal(";")
# Read lines from file:
with open('lines.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            result = parser.parseString(line)
            codes = [c[1] for c in result[1:-1]]
            # Do something with teh codez...
        except ParseException exc:
            # Oh noes: string doesn't match!
            continue
```

Cleaner than a regular expression, returns a list of codes (no need to `string.split`), and ignores any extra characters in the line, just like your example.

Comment: Thanks for pitching in with a pyparsing solution! Some other options to consider: define code as `Word('c'+string.digits, string.digits)`; then parser can just be `'start:' + delimitedList(code)("codes") + ';'`; the list of codes can be accessed through the results name as `codes = result.codes` -- in general I would keep the definition of things like code as clean as possible, and not mess them up with things like optional comma delimiters; instead add the commas at the next higher level of parser composition.  But your parser certainly gets the job done - congrats!

Comment: @Paul: Nice! Didn't know about `delimitedList` before now, and it totally makes sense that `Literal` be optional. Great stuff...thanks!

Comment: Interesting. I will have to look into pyparsing. Thanks for the post.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

sstr = re.compile(r'start:([^;]*);')
slst = re.compile(r'(?:c?)(\d+)')

mystr = "start: c12354, c3456, 34526; other stuff that I don't care about"
match = re.match(sstr, mystr)
if match:
    res = re.findall(slst, match.group(0))
```

results in

```
['12354', '3456', '34526']
```

Comment: Thanks for coding out the answer that madmik3 suggested - very helpful.