# Checking and removing extra symbols

Tags: python, symbols

I'm interested by removing extra symbols from strings in python.

What could by the more efficient and pythonic way to do that ? Is there some grammar module ?

My first idea would be to locate the more nested text and go through the left and the right, counting the opening and closing symbols. Then i remove the last one of the symbol counter that contain too much symbol.

An example would be this string

```
text = "(This (is an example)"
```

You can clearly see that the first parenthesis is not balanced by another one. So i want to delete it.

```
text = "This (is and example)"
```

The solution has to be independant of the position of the parentheses.

Others example could be :

```
text = "(This (is another example) )) (to) explain) the question"
```

That would become :

```
text = "(This (is another example) ) (to) explain the question"
```

Comment: Can you show some examples of what you're talking about.

Comment: Maybe checkout the [string docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods)

Comment: Ashwini Chaudhary is right, we need more info. But, from the info given, my first thought would be regular expressions. Look at re.sub(...).

Comment: Given the example, I think this has already been answered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454322/python-how-to-match-nested-parentheses-with-regex

Answer (score 0):

Had to break this into an answer for formatting. Check the [Python's regular expression module.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

If I'm understanding what you are asking, look at `re.sub`. You can use a regular expression to find the character you'd like to remove, and replace them with an empty string.

Suppose we want to remove all instances of '.', '&', and '*'.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "abc&def.ghi**jkl&"
>>> re.sub('[\.\&\*]', '', s)
'abcdefghijkl'
```

If the pattern to be matched is larger, you can use `re.compile` and pass that as the first argument to sub.

```
>>> r = re.compile('[\.\&\*]')
>>> re.sub(r, '', s)
'abcdefghijkl'
```

Hope this helps.