# Python: Regex match or condition?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like `{string}{string}{string}` which I'm able to parse by

```
import re
input_string = '{string}{string}{string}'
for match in re.finditer(r'{([^}]*)}', input_string):
     print str(match.group(0)) #outputs {string}
```

but I also want to catch strings with an asterick following a curly bracket.

```
input_string = '{string}{string}*{string}{string}*'
```

How do I modify the regex so that both `{string}` and `{string}*` will be caught?

I tried doing `r'{([^}]*)}|*'` but doesn't seem to be working.

Also, what if a string contains curly brackets? ex. `{string{3}}` How do I make sure only the outer {} is caught and not the one's inside?

Comment: what the....I was gonna accept a really great answer but it's gone.

Comment: Sorry, I had missed writing a response to your second question; undeleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `\*?` at the end of your regex to match an optional `*`.

```
import re
input_string = '{string}{string}*{string}{string}*'
for match in re.finditer(r'{([^}]*)}\*?', input_string):
     print str(match.group(0)) #outputs {string}
```

Output:

```
{string}
{string}*
{string}
{string}*
```

As for nested brackets, simple regular expressions cannot parse that. You *can* use recursive regular expressions for this, but it becomes unreadable ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12280660/320615)). You should use a proper parsing library, more discussion and examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454322/python-how-to-match-nested-parentheses-with-regex).

Comment: ah I see, it fails when there's a nested bracket

Comment: It will match the first closing bracket after an opening bracket. It'll match `{{a}` for input `{{a}}`.