# Recursive regexp in python?

Tags: python, regex, recursion

I have string:

```
acd (e(fg)h) ij)
```

I need to delete text within opened and coresponding closed bracket. So in example I need to delete

```
(e(fg)h)
```

In result I want to have

```
acd del ij)
```

I try to use next code:

```
re.sub(r'\((((?>[^()]+)|(?R))*)\)', r'del', 'acd (e(fg)h) ij)')
```

But python say:

```
sre_constants.error: unexpected end of pattern
```

Comment: Python does not support recursive regex. You might want to look into the [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module to access recursive regex (and some other regex syntax currently not supported by the re module).

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12280660/2235132) might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks Jerry and devnull!
**regex** module for python instead of default **re** module solved my issue

```
import regex
>>> regex.sub(r'\((((?>[^()]+)|(?R))*)\)', r'del', 'acd (e(fg)h) ij)')
'acd del ij)'
```