# Creating regex for a three letter string that contains at most 1 one of letter?

Tags: regex

If I wanted to match a string with As,Bs,Cs but my string cannot contain more than one 1 B and no more than 4Cs? How would I do this, without making it very long? I have a solution in which I make every combination of the letter B and arrangement of Cs and A*.

The Regex should match strings like:

AABCCCC

BAAACC

BAACACC

But not things like:

AABB

BBBACCC

CACACACC

Comment: show the input examples and the expected output

Comment: At the start of your regex, put two negative lookaheads: one for ``([^B]*B){2}``, and one for ``([^C]*C){5}``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it using lookahead:

If, at least 1 B and 1 C are mandatory :

```
^(?=[^B]*B[^B]*$)(?=(?:[^C]*C[^C]*){1,4}$)[ABC]+$
```

Else:

```
^(?=[^B]*B?[^B]*$)(?=(?:[^C]*C[^C]*){0,4}$)[ABC]*$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^                   : begining of line
(?=                 : lookahead, make sure we have:
    [^B]*B[^B]*     : 0 or more non B arround one B
    $               : until end of line
)                   : end lookahead
(?=                 : lookahead, make sure we have:
    (?:             : start non capture group
        [^C]*C[^C]* : 0 or more non C arround one C
    ){1,4}          : 1 upto 4 times
    $               : until end of line
)                   : end lookahead
[ABC]+              : 1 or more any of these letters
$                   : end of line
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible with a (basic) regex as counting will make the language larger than the regular language can handle. You can prove this with [the pumping lemma for the regular languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages])

You should list all possibles, when possible.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25309957/can-python-regex-count-parentheses)