# How to find what is inside of a selected parenthesis with regular expressions python?

Tags: python, regex, expression

Hi I have this query and I would like to extract exactly the `t0_0.pp,0` that is in `COALESCENSE()` parenthesis. I can have more parethesis before or after the COALESCENSE for this I am trying to use regular expressions like this (([^()]+))' but is givving me all inside all the parenthesis and I only wnat the COALESCENSE. Any idea?

```
select DISTINCT SUM(case when t0_0.pp is not null  then COALESCE(t0_0.pp,0)
else 0 end) from inventory_coverage_view t0_0 where  LOWER(t0_0.h) ='vg' AND t0_0.id = '9'
```

thank you in advance :)

Comment: Since regexes cannot count, there is no way to do that. You should use a parser.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5454322/67579

Comment: Use `r'COALESCE\((.*?)\)'` with `re.search` and once you get a match (`m = re.search(pat, s)`) get the Group 1 value (`m.group(1)`). That will work assuming there are no other `)` inside the `COALESCE` parentheses. Else, to parse arbitrary SQL queries, you really need a specific parser.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew perfect!!! Mny thanks!!!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, if that's the answer, please post it as an answer.

Comment: @JoanTriay: I posted the answer with explanations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To parse arbitrary SQL queries, you really need a specific parser.

If you know for sure there can be no other `)` inside the `COALESCE` parentheses, you may update your regex in the following way:

```
import re
pat = r"COALESCE\((.*?)\)"
s = "select DISTINCT SUM(case when t0_0.pp is not null  then COALESCE(t0_0.pp,0)\nelse 0 end) from inventory_coverage_view t0_0 where  LOWER(t0_0.h) ='vg' AND t0_0.id = '9'"
m = re.search(pat, s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1)) # => t0_0.pp,0
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XZS84l/1/) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/6ARXYz).

- `COALESCE\(`  - matches the `COALESCE(` literal substring
- `(.*?)` - captures any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, into Group 1
- `\)` - matches a literal `)`.

Comment: Is there a reason you use `.*?` instead of `[^)]*`?

Comment: @SebastianProske: Yes. In order not to overflow to the next line. I explained the pattern: *`.*?` ...any 0+ chars other than line break chars*. If there may be line breaks, then `[^)]*` is the natural solution. With questions based on assumptions, these nuances are not relevant (we just do not see the real data OP has). The main point here was adding left-hand side context. Besides, I think OP will have to precise the right-hand side boundary with more patterns, and then `.*?` will be more handy. To match line breaks, the `re.S` flag  can be passed: `re.search(pat, s, flags=re.S)`

Comment: I see, thanks. Please don't see my question as criticism, I was just curious.