# Regex: How to capture groups of parentheses if followed by a set of operators?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, parentheses

```
\(([^\\(\\)]+)\)
```

My regex above captures everything between each set of brackets of the form

```
(Hello OR there) AND (big AND wide AND world)
```

I get

```
Hello OR there
big AND wide AND world
```

But it falls down when there are parentheses inside the terms within the brackets

```
(Hello OR there AND messing(it)up) AND (big AND wide AND world)
```

Returns

```
it
big AND wide AND world
```

Whereas I want

```
Hello OR there AND messing(it)up
big AND wide AND world
```

I'm not sure if that's possible with regex or what the best approach would be?

Comment: It's re in standard lib Python.

Comment: Is it possible in the improved regex module?

Comment: @user1561108 See my edit.

Comment: E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12280660/3832970. I can add more if you wish

Comment: Yeah, missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following pattern:

```
\(((?:[^()]+|(?R))*+)\)
```

The `(?R)` subexpression [recurses the entire pattern if possible](https://regex101.com/r/cfdYCf/2/debugger).

You may try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/cfdYCf/2/).

---

For input:

```
(Hello OR there AND messing(it)up) AND (big AND wide AND world)
```

Captured groups are:

```
Group 1.    47-79   `Hello OR there AND messing(it)up`
Group 1.    86-108  `big AND wide AND world`
```

---

If you are working in Python, you can use the `regex` module:

```
import regex

mystring = '(Hello OR there AND messing(it)up) AND (big AND wide AND world)'
print(regex.findall('(?V1)\(((?:[^()]+|(?R))*+)\)',mystring))
```

Prints:

```
['Hello OR there AND messing(it)up', 'big AND wide AND world']
```