# How to match text outside any parens groups using Python regex?

Tags: python, regex

I can't find general solution within tons of solutions. Just want to extract text outside any of parens group.

Ideally, this text

> Application ( Change  (Sui Generis (haha) ) cafe & laundrette) Monday
>   to Thursday. (To match the sun).

match with 2 groups:

- within parens: `" Change  (Sui Generis (haha) ) cafe & laundrette"` and `"To match the sun"`
- outside (at zero level) parens: `"Application"` + `"Monday to Thursday."`

Simple `\(.*?\)` or `\(.*\)` fails of course. I need to use non-capturing group I guess but how?

Comment: If you need a regex solution it is [already posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12280660/3832970).

Comment: Thanks. So I can use `print(result.captures('rec'))` to get phrases in parens but how to get the rest? I can't use `result.noncaptures('rec')`

Comment: There are several approaches: 1) split with that regex, 2) grab the indices of the parenthetical substrings and build the resulting list using them and the input string, 3) replace the matches once found with some text and then split with that text.

Comment: Ok. You helped me, thanks.