# Regular expression to parse css

Tags: python, css, regex, parsing

I hope I find you well.

I realise that a generic regular expression to fit all css won't cut it in all cases, however I am parsing a particular piece of css so I can tweak this expression to fit my needs.

Having scoured SO, I did find some very useful regular expressions which I have combined with great success into the following:

```
parsed_css = re.findall(r'([\[\]=\"\#\.\w\-\,\s\n\r\t:@*]+)(\{[^\{\}].*?\})', css, re.DOTALL)
```

This produces something like:

```
Selector: '.div-wrapper' rules: '{position:absolute;z-index:4;background:none!important;border:none!important}'
```

However, I encounter problems when coming across keyframes rules like this:

```
@keyframes mymove { from {top: 0px;} to {top: 200px;}}
```

Obviously the curlies are the problem but I'm hoping someone has some look ahead / look behind magic to produce the following in these rare instances:

```
Selector: '@keyframes mymove'
Rules: '{from {top: 0px;} to {top: 200px;}}'
```

Many thanks!
Darren

Comment: For anything beyond toy implementations or learning exercises, I strongly suggest you use a proper parser instead of regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pyparsing](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing) to parse such nested parentheses.

```py
import pyparsing as pp

string = '@keyframes mymove {from {top: 0px;} to {top: 200px;}}'
pattern = pp.Regex(r'^.*?(?= \{)') + pp.original_text_for(pp.nested_expr('{', '}'))
selector, rules = pattern.parse_string(string)

# Tests
assert selector == '@keyframes mymove'
assert rules == '{from {top: 0px;} to {top: 200px;}}'
```

* `pyparsing` can be installed by `pip install pyparsing`

See also this post: [Python: How to match nested parentheses with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454322/python-how-to-match-nested-parentheses-with-regex/5454510#5454510)