# Issue in pattern matching using python regex

Tags: python, substring, python-re, regex-greedy

i am facing issues while trying to cut out a substring from a string using python regex. the problem statement is that i want to take any substring matching the following format from a bigger string

```
some_var:struct<some_variables>
```

In doing so, i got into three corner case scenarios and let me explain those scenarios in details

**Scenario1 :-**

```
s='firstname:string,middlename:double,lastname:struct<last1:int,last2:array<string>>,addr:string'
match = re.search(r'\w[a-zA-Z]*:struct<.*>,',s)
>>> print(match.group())
lastname:struct<last1:int,last2:array<string>>,
```

the above code works fine.

**Scenario2:-**

```
subdtyp = 'firstname:string,middlename:double,lastname:struct<last1:int,last2:array<string>>,last3:array<string>,last4:struct<last41:int,last42:string>'
>>> match = re.search(r'\w[a-zA-Z]*:struct<.*>,',subdtyp)
>>> print(match.group())
lastname:struct<last1:int,last2:array<string>>,last3:array<string>,
```

in this case on using the above regex format, due to greedy matching i am getting a string which is more than what is expected (`last3:array<string>,`) is the extra bit of information that is coming. So i changed that to non-greedy matching like below

```
>>> match = re.search(r'\w[a-zA-Z]*:struct<.*?>,',subdtyp)
>>> print(match.group())
lastname:struct<last1:int,last2:array<string>>,
```

this time the result is coming fine and what i want

**Scenario 3 :-**

```
subdtyp2 = 'firstname:string,middlename:double,lastname:struct<last4:struct<last41:int,last42:string>,last2:array<string>>,last3:array<string>'
>>> match = re.search(r'\w[a-zA-Z]*:struct<.*?>,',subdtyp2)
>>> print(match.group())
lastname:struct<last4:struct<last41:int,last42:string>,
```

here we are not getting the completed result as (`last2:array<string>`) portion is missed out for non-greedy matching.

Can somebody please help me in providing me a regex which will satisfy all the above conditions ?

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5454510/16521194), regex woulld not be the best way to handle nested expressions. A better way would be `pyparsing`.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5454510/16521194), I get something like this:

```py
import pyparsing

string = 'firstname:string,middlename:double,lastname:struct<last1:int,last2:array<string>>,addr:string'
thecontent = pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.alphanums) | ":" | ","
parens = pyparsing.nestedExpr("<", ">", content=f"<{thecontent}>")

a = parens.parseString(string).asList()[0]
print(a[a.index('struct')+1])

# ['last1', ':', 'int', ',', 'last2', ':', 'array', ['string']]
```

We must define `thecontent` as every character other than the nesting ones, while here `parens` are the nesting ones. Additionally, like in JSON, you can't start from something else than a nesting character, thus why the `content=f"<{thecontent}>"`.
As far as I've understood, you want to find the content of the structs, this should allow you to do exactly this.