# Converted nested IF conditions to a nestedList in Python

Tags: python-3.x

Could any one please help me converting the below IF conditions to a list. Each IF condition has one IF block, one 'then' (separated by comma) block and one 'else block'. Nothing really worked close so far.

single IF condition looks like this:

```
IF(IN(COL1, 'val'), COL2, COL3)
```

Real-time scenario has nested conditions like this

```
IF(IN(COL1, 'val1'), 'A', IF(COL2 = 'val2', IF(COL3 = 'val3', 'B', 'C'), 'D')
```

Looking for a nested list for every IF condition with 'then' and 'else' as separate items like these: ('then' and 'else' can be another IF statement that should follow the same listing process)

```
["IF(IN(COL1, 'val1')", 'A', ["IF(COL2 = 'val2'", ["IF(COL3 = 'val3'", 'B', 'C'], 'D']]
```

or

```
["IN(COL1 = 'val1'", 'A', ["COL2 = 'val2'", ["COL3 = 'val3'", 'B', 'C'], 'D']]
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: I would suggest having a look at the [formulas](https://pypi.org/project/formulas/) library... Don't reinvent the wheel (without a good reason)

Comment: I was able to do this by replacing the braces comes with IN condition to curly braces first. Then I used this as reference to change all the IF statements into a corresponding lists. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23185540/turn-a-string-with-nested-parenthesis-into-a-nested-list-python

Comment: with this one change in the code -  def parse_nested(text, left=r'IF[(]', right=r'[)]', sep=r',(?![^{]*[}])'):