# Regular Expression conflict due to user inputs

Tags: python, regex

I would like to split a string into 2 groups, based on a regular expression. The string has basically the following structure:

```
some text (data1 | data2 | data3 | data4)
```

I've used a simple regular expression as follows:

```
re.match("^(?P<title>.*)\((?P<data>.*)\)$", s)
```

It works fine provided there are no parenthesis in the string, that would conflict with the regular expression.

But if there are parenthesis in one of the groups, it outputs an unexpected result:

```
>>> import re
>>> def process_string1(s):
...    r = re.match("^(?P<title>.*?)\((?P<data>.*)\)$", s)
...    return r.groups()
...
>>> def process_string2(s):
...    r = re.match("^(?P<title>.*)\((?P<data>.*)\)$", s)
...    return r.groups()
...
>>> s = "this is an example (detail) (data1 | data2 | data3 | data4)"
>>> print process_string1(s)
('this is an example ', 'detail) (data1 | data2 | data3 | data4')      # Wrong
>>> print process_string2(s)
('this is an example (detail) ', 'data1 | data2 | data3 | data4')      # Good
>>> s = "this is another example (data1 (detail) | data2 | data3 | data4)"
>>> print process_string1(s)
('this is another example ', 'data1 (detail) | data2 | data3 | data4') # Good
>>> print process_string2(s)
('this is another example (data1 ', 'detail) | data2 | data3 | data4') # Wrong
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Python regular expressions are "greedy" by default.  They grab the longest string that satisfies the expression.  The first part will grab '(' if there are other '(' in the string.  Maybe you should change '.*' with '[^(]*'?

Answer (score 1):

See these answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1758162/3821009
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/546457/3821009

In short, regex is not the tool for matching recursive / nested structures, like you have. You are asking a regex to match:

```
something (something (someting) something)
```

which is recursive, as the innermost `something` can potentially again be `something (something) something`. Regex is not suitable tool for this, you should use a [parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) for this. See these questions for more information:

- [Python parsing bracketed blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651487/python-parsing-bracketed-blocks)
- [How to parse a string and return a nested array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140850/how-to-parse-a-string-and-return-a-nested-array)

Answer (score 1):

Many flavors of regex support recursion, or nested constructs. Python's engine doesn't currently support it, but a replacement module is in the works, and it does support recursion:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex

Answer (score 0):

I have finally adapted my code as follows:

```
>>> import re
>>> def process_string(s):
...    r = re.match("^(?P<title>.*)\((?P<data>.*)\)$", s)    
...    if '(' in r.group('title') and not ')' in r.group('title'):
...        r = re.match("^(?P<title>.*?)\((?P<data>.*)\)$", s)
...    return r.groups()
```

Which produces the result I was expecting:

```
>>> print process_string("this is an example (detail) (data1 | data2 | data3 | data4)")
('this is an example (detail) ', 'data1 | data2 | data3 | data4')

>>> print process_string("this is an example (data1 (detail) | data2 | data3 | data4)")
('this is an example ', 'data1 (detail) | data2 | data3 | data4')
```