# Regex for multi-dimentional float array. Match space or no-space after each array value

Tags: javascript, python, regex

I'm new to RegEx. I need to exactly match the given value to be used in location fencing. (problems are stated on the bottom-most part of thread). I will be using this on **javascript** and posibly in **python**. These are the formats that I must allow:

1. `[[1.32, 42.14],[1.32, 42.124]]` //2d array with only 2 floating values in each 1d arrays
2. `[[[1.32, 42.14],[1.32, 42.124]],[[1.32, 42.14],[1.32, 42.124]]]` // an array of the 2d array above #1
3. `[[[[1.32, 42.14],[1.32, 42.124]],[[1.32, 42.14],[1.32, 42.124]]],[[[1.32, 42.14],[1.32, 42.124]],[[1.32, 42.14],[1.32, 42.124]]]]` // an array of the array above. #2

I managed to create these expressions below:

**test 1** - Test for float array with only 2 values inside: e.g. `[1.23,42.124]`

RegEx:

```
(\[((([0-9]*)[.])?[0-9]+[,]?){2}(?<!,)\])
```

**test 2** - Test for arrays of **test 1**: e.g. `[[1.23,42.124],[1.23,42.124]]`

RegEx:

```
(\[(((\[((([0-9]*)[.])?[0-9]+[,]?){2}(?<![,])\])[,]?)+)(?<![,])\])
```

**test 3** - Test for array of **test 2**: e.g. `[[[1.23,42.124],[1.23,42.124]],[[1.23,42.124],[1.23,42.124]]]`

RegEx:

```
(\[((\[(((\[((([0-9]*)[.])?[0-9]+[,]?){2}(?<![,])\])[,]?)+)(?<![,])\])[,]?)+(?<![,])\])
```

**test 4** - test for array of **test 3**: e.g. `[[[[1.23,42.124],[1.23,42.124]],[[1.23,42.124],[1.23,42.124]]],[[[1.23,42.124],[1.23,42.124]],[[1.23,42.124],[1.23,42.124]]]]`

RegEx:

```
(\[(((\[((\[(((\[((([0-9]*)[.])?[0-9]+[,]?){2}(?<![,])\])[,]?)+)(?<![,])\])[,]?)+(?<![,])\])[,]?)+)(?<![,])\])
```

So I **completed the expression** by combining **test 2 to test 4** together in an `|` (or):

Complete Regex:

```
/(\[(((\[((([0-9]*)[.])?[0-9]+[,]?){2}(?<![,])\])[,]?)+)(?<![,])\])|(\[((\[(((\[((([0-9]*)[.])?[0-9]+[,]?){2}(?<![,])\])[,]?)+)(?<![,])\])[,]?)+(?<![,])\])|(\[(((\[((\[(((\[((([0-9]*)[.])?[0-9]+[,]?){2}(?<![,])\])[,]?)+)(?<![,])\])[,]?)+(?<![,])\])[,]?)+)(?<![,])\])/g
```

These are my current **problems with this expression**:

1. does not accept spaces in between array values. e.g. accepts `[1.32,42.124]` but `[1.32, 42.124]` is erroneous.
2. I manage to mismatch it if it has trailing comma on last value `[[1.32,42.124],[1.32,42.124],]`. But it accepts succeeding values without commas e.g. `[[1.32,42.124][1.32,42.124]]`.
3. Last is it does not accept typical multi-line formatted json.

I need to accept spaces in between array values, and do not accept succeeding values without commas.

Comment: Don't do this in regex... it's recursive and regex is the worst thing to handle it.

Comment: @MikeGuelfi What do you suggest sir?

Comment: This has a strong relation to your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140850/how-to-parse-a-string-and-return-a-nested-array

Comment: There's no indication of the root problem, but the answer isn't regex. If as @mrEvgenX suspects it's validating the input his suggestion is good. But if you're expecting valid input anyway, you could collect it directly into an array?