# Match content between curly braces than also can contain curly braces

Tags: python, regex

If I have a string:

```
s = aaa{bbb}ccc{ddd{eee}fff}ggg
```

is it possible to find all matches based on outer curly braces?

```
m = re.findall(r'\{.+?\}', s, re.DOTALL)
```

returns

```
['{bbb}', '{ddd{eee}']
```

but I need:

```
 ['{bbb}', '{ddd{eee}fff}']
```

Is it possible with python regex?

Comment: In the general case [you don't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099178/matching-nested-structures-with-regular-expressions-in-python)

Comment: Python doesn't support recursion in regex (neither does it support balancing groups).

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this regex also.

```
\{(?:{[^{}]*}|[^{}])*}
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aW4fW4/1)

```
>>> s = 'aaa{bbb}ccc{ddd{eee}fff}ggg'
>>> re.findall(r'\{(?:{[^{}]*}|[^{}])*}', s)
['{bbb}', '{ddd{eee}fff}']
```

Use recursive regex for 1 level deep.

```
\{(?:(?R)|[^{}])*}
```

Code:

```
>>> import regex
>>> regex.findall(r'\{(?:(?R)|[^{}])*}', s)
['{bbb}', '{ddd{eee}fff}']
```

But this would be supported by the external `regex` module.

Answer (score 4):

If you want it to work in any depth, but don't necessarily need to use regex, you can implement a simple stack based automaton:

```
s = "aaa{bbb}ccc{ddd{eee}fff}ggg"

def getStuffInBraces(text):
    stuff=""
    count=0
    for char in text:
        if char=="{":
            count += 1
        if count > 0:
            stuff += char
        if char=="}":
            count -= 1
        if count == 0 and stuff != "":
            yield stuff
            stuff=""
```

`getStuffInBraces` is an iterator, so if you want a list of results, you can use `print(list(getStuffInBraces(s)))`.

Answer (score 3):

```
{(?:[^{}]*{[^{]*})*[^{}]*}
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fA6wE2/28

P.S It will only work the `{}` is not more than `1` level deep.