# Python Regular Express Lookahead multiple conditions

Tags: python, regex

My string looks like this:

```
string = "*[EQ](@[Type],'A,B,C',@[Type],*[EQ](@[Type],D,E,F))"
```

The ideal output list is:

```
['@[Type]', 'A,B,C', '@[Type]', '*[EQ](@[Type],D,E,F)']
```

So I can parse the string as:

```
if @[Type] in ('A,B,C') then @[Type] else *[EQ](@[Type],D,E,F)
```

The challenge is to find all the commas followed by @, ' or *. I've tried the following code but it doesn't work:

```
interM = re.search(r"\*\[EQ\]\((.+)(?=,@|,\*|,\')+,(.+)\)", string)
print(interM.groups())
```

Edit:

The ultimate goal is to parse out the 4 components of the input string:

```
*[EQ](Value, Target, ifTrue, ifFalse)
```

Comment: where and why did the first `*EQ(` go?

Comment: Your input seems to be a nested structure, which is something regular expressions are not the right tool for. Please either: explain its grammar in abstract terms or: show and confirm all variations you are dealing with.

Comment: @Tomalak more info added. can you explain a bit more why RE might not be a good tool for nested structure? sorry I'm new to python and this question seems a bit silly...

Comment: What is the expected behavior if there is a missing comma between expressions?

Comment: @Nip Regular expressions are incapable of capturing nesting. It's a technical limitation. If your `ifFalse` can contain unlimited levels, regex will be unable to capture the correct closing quotes. See here for more explanations and alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099178/matching-nested-structures-with-regular-expressions-in-python. There are any number of posts that discuss regex and nested input, if you search around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "*[EQ](@[Type],'A,B,C',@[Type],*[EQ](@[Type],D,E,F))"
>>> re.split(r"^\*\[EQ\]\(|\)$|,(?=[@'*])", string)[1:-1]
['@[Type]', "'A,B,C'", '@[Type]', '*[EQ](@[Type],D,E,F)']
```

Although, if you are looking for a more robust solution I'd highly recommend a [Lexical Analyzer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) such as [flex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_lexical_analyser).

Answer (score 2):

```
x="*[EQ](@[Type],'A,B,C',@[Type],*[EQ](@[Type],D,E,F))"
print re.findall(r"@[^,]+|'[^']+'|\*.*?\([^\)]*\)",re.findall(r"\*\[EQ\]\((.*?)\)$",x)[0])
```

Output:

```
['@[Type]', "'A,B,C'", '@[Type]', '*[EQ](@[Type],D,E,F)']
```

You can try something of this sort.You have not mentioned the logic or anything so not sure if this can be scaled.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help! I add more information in the question, not sure if it clarifies though.