# bounding strings between two characters in regex

Tags: python, regex, string

I am using `<[^<>]+>` in order to extract substrings between `<` and `>`, as the following:

`<abc>, <?.sdfs/>, <sdsld\>`, etc.

I am not trying to parse HTML tags, or something similar. My only issue is extracting strings between `<` and `>`.

But sometimes, there might be substrings like the following:

```
</</\/\asa></dsdsds><sdsfsa>>
```

In that case, all string should be matched, instead of 3 substrings. Because all string is covered by `<` and `>`.

How can I modify my regex to do that?

Comment: Such strings aren’t part of a regular language, so a regex is probably the wrong approach.

Comment: Depending on the language you are using, there are special regex constructs to do it. C# for example has one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003799/what-are-regular-expression-balancing-groups)

Comment: @xanatos, I am using python.

Comment: There is an old question about this: [Matching Nested Structures With Regular Expressions in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1099178/613130)

Comment: And there is a newer python regex library that should do it: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex (the *Nested sets and set operations are supported.* part)

Comment: It is not exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @yusuf: With PyPi `regex` module, you may use this - [`<(?:[^<>]++|(?R))*>`](https://regex101.com/r/qT5FyU/1)

Comment: can I use re.search for this?

Comment: @yusuf: **Only** with PyPi regex module. Or write your own method using stack.

Comment: Yea the old stack way seems best in this case :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use regex. Use the traditional way to do this. Make a stack and if there's more than one '<' keep appending else break and append the whole thing.

But just make sure to handle the double back slashes that somehow crop up :-/

```
def find_tags(your_string)
    ans = []
    stack = []
    tag_no = 0

    for c in your_string:
        if c=='<':
            tag_no+=1
            if tag_no>1:
                stack.append(c)
        elif c=='>':
            if tag_no==1:
                ans.append(''.join(stack))
                tag_no=0
                stack=[]
             else:
                  tag_no = tag_no-1
                  stack.append(c)
        elif tag_no>0:
             stack.append(c)
    return ans
```

Output below

```
find_tags(r'<abc>, <?.sdfs/>, <sdsld\>')
['abc', '?.sdfs/', 'sdsld\\']
find_tags(r'</</\/\asa></dsdsds><sdsfsa>>')
['/</\\/\\asa></dsdsds><sdsfsa>']
```

Note: Works in O(n) as well.

Comment: abhishek, I want to include < and >.

Answer (score 1):

Refer this
[Regular Expression to match outer brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-outer-brackets)
I'm trying to implement the same using `<` & `>`.

Or How about a small method for this:

```
def recursive_bracket_parser(s, i):
while i < len(s):
    if s[i] == '<':
        i = recursive_bracket_parser(s, i+1)
    elif s[i] == '>':
        return i+1
    else:
        # process whatever is at s[i]
        i += 1
return i
```

Source: [How can I match nested brackets using regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952113/how-can-i-match-nested-brackets-using-regex)