# How to escape specific whitespaces when splitting line into words with regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to split a string into a list of words (here "word" means *arbitrary sequence of non-whitespace characters*), but also keep the groups of consecutive whitespaces that have been used as separators (because the number of whitespaces is significant in my data). For this simple task, I know that the following regex would do the job (I use Python as an illustrative language, but the code can be easily adapted to any language including regexes):

```
import re
regexA = re.compile(r"(\S+)")
print(regexA.split("aa b+b   cc dd!    :ee  "))
```

produces the expected output:

```
['', 'aa', ' ', 'b+b', '   ', 'cc', ' ', 'dd!', '    ', ':ee', '  ']
```

Now the hard part: when a word includes an opening parenthesis, all the whitespaces encountered until the matching closing parenthesis should not be considered as word separators. In other words:

```
regexB.split("aa b+b   cc(dd! :ee (ff gg) hh) ii  ")
```

should produce:

```
['', 'aa', ' ', 'b+b', '   ', 'cc(dd! :ee (ff gg) hh)', ' ', 'ii', '  ']
```

Using

```
regexB = re.compile(r'([^(\s]*\([^)]*\)|\S+)')
```

works for a single pair of parentheses, but fails when there are inner parentheses. How could I improve the regex to correctly skip inner parentheses?

And the final question: in my data, only words starting with `%` should be tested for the "parenthesis rule" (`regexB`), the other words should be treated by `regexA`. I have no idea how to combine two regexes in a single split.

Any hint is warmly welcome...

Comment: Regex can't match nested structures like parentheses. You'll have to write some code.

Comment: @Aran: I agree for the general case, but in my case, I know that there is at most one inner pair of parenthesis. Does this constraint change the pb?

Comment: As Aran-Fey said, regex can't understand nesting. For example, for a string like `(a b (c d) e f)`, if your regex is non-greedy, then it will match `(a b (c d)` and `(c d)`. If it's greedy, it will match `(a b (c d) e f)` and `(c d) e f)`. Both of those are problematic, in different ways.

Comment: However, Python does have parsing libraries that you might want to look into, as explained in this answer: [Matching Nested Structures With Regular Expressions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1101046/7315159)

Comment: [Here is a hint](http://rextester.com/RJV53548).

Comment: @Wiktor: Using `finditer` instead of `split` is a very clever approach to solve the problem. Thanks a lot! I'm going to write a summary here, as I am not sure that the link on **rextester** lasts very long

Comment: I can post the answer if you wish to accept. Note that PyPi regex module is used there. Not the regular `re`.

Comment: @Wiktor: Yes, after reading the answer by @Thm, I understood that your solution also requires subroutines which are not supported by the standard `re`. So I mixed your respective answers to get a rather clean solution working in standard `re`...

Answer (score 1):

In the `PCRE regex` engine, `sub-routine` is supported and `recursive pattern` seems workable for the case including `balanced nested` parentheses.

```
(?m)\s+(?=[^()]*(\([^()]*(?1)?[^()]*\))*[^()]*$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/77),,, in which `(?1`) means calling sub-routine 1, `(\([^()]*(?1)?[^()]*\))`, namely `recursive pattern` which includes `caller`, `(?1)`

But python does not support `sub-routine`pattern in `regex`.

So I tried first replacing every `(` , `)` with another distinctive character( `@` in this example) and applying the regex to split and finally turn `@` back to `(` or `)` respectively in my pythone script.

Regex for spliting.

```
(?m)(\s+)(?=[^@]*(?:(?:@[^@]*){2})*$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/80),,, in which I changed your separator `\S+` to consecutive spaces `\s+` because `@`,`(`,`)` are included in `[\S]`' `possible characters set`.

Python script may be like this

```
import re
ss="""aa b+b   cc(dd! :ee ((ff gg)) hh) ii  """
ss=re.sub(r"\(|\)","@",ss)      #repacing every `(`,`)` to `@`

regx=re.compile(r"(?m)(\s+)(?=[^@]*(?:(?:@[^@]*){2})*$)")
m=regx.split(ss)
for i in range(len(m)):         # turn `@` back to `(` or `)` respectively 
    n= m[i].count('@')
    if n < 2: continue
    else: 
        for j in range(int(n/2)):
            k=m[i].find('@'); m[i]=m[i][:k]+'('+m[i][k+1:]
        m[i]= m[i].replace("@",')')
print(m)
```

Output is

```
['aa', ' ', 'b+b', '   ', 'cc(dd! :ee ((ff gg)) hh)', ' ', 'ii', '  ', '']
```

Comment: It took me some time, after reading your answer, to understand the power of subroutines (too bad that the standard `re` module does not support them). But I like your substitution approach that works with the standard `re` module. I just twisted it a little bit by including @Wiktor's `finditer` idea to get shorter and cleaner code.

Comment: Thanks for your info. Wiktor's method is great:-)

Answer (score 0):

Finally after having tested several ideas based on the answers proposed by @Wiktor Stribiżew and @Thm Lee, I came to bunch of solutions dealing with different levels of complexity. To reduce dependency, I wanted to stick to the `re` module from the Python standard library, so here is the code:

```
import re

text = "aa b%b(   %cc(dd! (:ee ff) gg) %hh ii)  "

# Solution 1: don't process parentheses at all
regexA = re.compile(r'(\S+)')
print(regexA.split(text))

# Solution 2: works for non-nested parentheses
regexB = re.compile(r'(%[^(\s]*\([^)]*\)|\S+)')
print(regexB.split(text))

# Solution 3: works for one level of nested parentheses
regexC = re.compile(r'(%[^(\s]*\((?:[^()]*\([^)]*\))*[^)]*\)|\S+)')
print(regexC.split(text))

# Solution 4: works for arbitrary levels of nested parentheses
n, words = 0, []
for word in regexA.split(text):
    if n: words[-1] += word
    else: words.append(word)
    if n or (word and word[0] == '%'):
        n += word.count('(') - word.count(')')
print(words)
```

Here is the generated output:

```
Solution 1: ['', 'aa', ' ', 'b%b(', '   ', '%cc(dd!', ' ', '(:ee', ' ', 'ff)', ' ', 'gg)', ' ', '%hh', ' ', 'ii)', '  ']
Solution 2: ['', 'aa', ' ', 'b%b(', '   ', '%cc(dd! (:ee ff)', ' ', 'gg)', ' ', '%hh', ' ', 'ii)', '  ']
Solution 3: ['', 'aa', ' ', 'b%b(', '   ', '%cc(dd! (:ee ff) gg)', ' ', '%hh', ' ', 'ii)', '  ']
Solution 4: ['', 'aa', ' ', 'b%b(', '   ', '%cc(dd! (:ee ff) gg)', ' ', '%hh', ' ', 'ii)', '  ']
```

As stated in the OP, for my specific data, escaping whitespaces in parentheses has only to be done for words starting with `%`, other parentheses (e.g. word `b%b(` in my example) are not considered are special. If you want to escape whitespaces inside any pair of parentheses, simply remove the `%`char in the regexes. Here is the result with that modification:

```
Solution 1: ['', 'aa', ' ', 'b%b(', '   ', '%cc(dd!', ' ', '(:ee', ' ', 'ff)', ' ', 'gg)', ' ', '%hh', ' ', 'ii)', '  ']
Solution 2: ['', 'aa', ' ', 'b%b(   %cc(dd! (:ee ff)', ' ', 'gg)', ' ', '%hh', ' ', 'ii)', '  ']
Solution 3: ['', 'aa', ' ', 'b%b(   %cc(dd! (:ee ff) gg)', ' ', '%hh', ' ', 'ii)', '  ']
Solution 4: ['', 'aa', ' ', 'b%b(   %cc(dd! (:ee ff) gg) %hh ii)', '  ']
```