# Match a valid list

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

I want to know, with regex, if a list is well-written or not.
A well-written list start with '[' and ends with ']' and can handle numbers or other lists or be empty.

Example of valid lists:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, [6, 9], 4]
[[1, 5], 2, [2, 7, [[]], 8, 9, [1]], []]
```

As you can see this is recursive. So, What regular expression should I use in this case?

Comment: I want to know if the entire list is valid or not.

Comment: Duplicate of [Regular expression to match balanced parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-balanced-parentheses), [Matching Nested Structures With Regular Expressions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1099178/8967612), and [Python: How to match nested parentheses with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5454322/8967612)

Comment: Python's regular expressions can't handle recursive brackets of arbitrary nesting level. You need a parser like e. g. Pyparsing or write a simple one.

Comment: If that is your syntax, Python's `ast` module can verify it, e.g. `ast.literal_eval('[1,[6,9],4]')`. It will raise an error if not balanced.  You other literals, though, like `1.5` or `'a'` in the lists, so if you want strict checking use `pyparsing`.

Comment: Assuming input is a string, you could do eval(input_str) and catch SyntaxError and report invalid if there is SyntaxError

Comment: `eval` can be used to execute code.  `ast.literal_eval` is safer.