# Python ReGex Pattern Finder

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to get better with ReGex in Python, and I am trying to figure out how I would isolate a specific substring in some text.  I have some text, and that text could look like any of the following:

```py
possible_strings = [
    "some text (and words) more text (and words)",
    "textrighthere(with some more)",
    "little trickier (this time) with (all of (the)(values))"
]
```

With each string, despite the fact that I don't know what's in them, I know it always ends with some information in parentheses.  To include examples like #3, where the final pair of parentheses have parentheses in them.

How could I go about using `re`/ReGex to isolate the text only inside of the last pair of parentheses?  So in the previous example, I would want the output to be:

```py
output = [
    "and words",
    "with some more",
    "all of (the)(values)"
]
```

Any tips or help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In python you can use the `regex` module as it is supports recurssion:

```
import regex
pat = r'(\((?:[^()]|(?1))*\))$'
regex.findall(pat, '\n'.join(possible_strings), regex.M)

['(and words)', '(with some more)', '(all of (the)(values))']
```

The regex might be quite complicated for a beginner. [Click here for the explanations and examples](https://regex101.com/r/nF380F/1)

Abit of explanation:

```
( # 1st Capturing Group  
   \( # matches the character ( 
      (?:#Non-capturing group
         [^()] # 1st Alternative Match a single character not present in the character class
         | # or
         (?1) #2nd Alternative matches the expression defined in the 1st capture group recursively
      ) # closes capturing group
     * # matches zero or more times
   \) #matches the character ) 
$ asserts position at the end of a line
```

Comment: @PranavHosangadi editted

Answer (score 0):

For the first two, start matching an opening bracket, that could be either of these:

```
"some text (and words) more text (and words)"
           ^                     ^
```

followed by anything which isn't an opening bracket:

```
"some text (and words) more text (and words)"
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^X^^^^^^^^^^^
                                 |- starting at the first ( hit 
                                    another ( which isn't allowed.
```

followed by end of line. Only the last () fits "no more ( until end of line".

```py
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('\([^(]+\)$', "some text (and words) more text (and words)")
['(and words)']
```

RegEx is not a good fit for your third example; there's no easy way to pair up the parens, you may have to install and use [a different regex engine](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) to get nested structure support. See also

- [Matching Nested Structures With Regular Expressions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099178/matching-nested-structures-with-regular-expressions-in-python)
- [Python: How to match nested parentheses with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454322/python-how-to-match-nested-parentheses-with-regex)